# Generating Radial Gradients with Multiple Center Points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm running into a weird issue with making radial gradients with multiple circles in them. At the moment, I'm taking a list of center points, as well as a list of associated radii and generating a black and white texture from it. I have a toggle as well to change the direction of the gradient.

Here is my code, straight from the system it's in:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

[CreateAssetMenu(menuName =("Texture/Gradient/Circle"))]
public class Circle : GradientShape
{
    public override Texture2D CreateGradient(NoiseGenerator.GradientTexture gt, int width, int height)
    {
        //Ensures no errors
        //If there is no ceneterpoints given, and by extension, no falloff distances given, then default to a circle in the middle of the texture, with a radius of half the width
        List<Vector2> centerPoints = new List<Vector2>();
        List<float> fallOffDistances = new List<float>();
        if (gt.points == null)
        {
            centerPoints.Add(new Vector2(width / 2, height / 2));
            fallOffDistances.Add(width/2);
        }
        else
        {
            if (gt.points.Count == 0)
            {
                centerPoints.Add(new Vector2(width / 2, height / 2));
                fallOffDistances.Add(width/2);
            }
            else
            {
                centerPoints = gt.points;
                fallOffDistances = gt.fallOffDistances;
            }
        }


        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                Vector2 currentPixel = new Vector2(x, y);
                Color newColor;

                int index = FindClosestPointIndex(currentPixel, centerPoints, fallOffDistances);
                Vector2 closestPoint = centerPoints[index];
                float falloffDistance = fallOffDistances[index];
                float distance = Vector2.Distance(currentPixel, closestPoint);
                if (gt.direction)
                {
                    if (distance <= falloffDistance)
                    {
                        float sample = distance / (falloffDistance * gt.fallOffStrength);
                        newColor = new Color(sample, sample, sample); //Turn black the closer you are to the point 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newColor = Color.white;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (distance >= falloffDistance)
                    {
                        float sample = falloffDistance / (distance * gt.fallOffStrength);
                        newColor = new Color(sample, sample, sample); //Turn white the closer you are to the point 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newColor = Color.white;
                    }
                }

                texture.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
            }
        }
        texture.Apply();
        return texture;
    }


    int FindClosestPointIndex(Vector2 start, List<Vector2> points, List<float> fallOffDistances)
    {
        List<float> distances = new List<float>();
        for(int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
        {
            distances.Insert(0, (Vector2.Distance(start, points[i])));
        }

        int index = distances.IndexOf(distances.Min());

        return index;
    }
}
```

It works fine with one circle.
[image]

But never two

[image]

Or three

[image]

My desired result is:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfQPi.jpg)

I know the issue has to do with my FindClosestPointIndex method.
I just don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 0):

You calculate point color basing on a distance to closest center. So, if you have 3 centers, you just split your texture onto 3 separate areas around these centers. That's why you don't have a smooth gradient: color in each area calculated independently from others -> you see edges.

What you need, is to calculate each point of you texture based on every gradient center. Something like this (pseudocode):

```
float brightness1 = distanceFromCenter1 * falloff1;
float brightness2 = distanceFromCenter2 * falloff2;
float brightness3 = distanceFromCenter3 * falloff3;
float pointBrightness = (brightness1 + brightness2 + brightness3) / 3f;
```